# Cannot find geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-spatialite-plugin.zip

Tags: geoserver

Folks I am creating a new install of GeoServer.  Now attempting to install the spatialite plugin.  (geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-spatialite-plugin.zip)

However plugin is not in the 2.17 community latest:

https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.17.x/community-latest/

According to the GeoServer instructions, that is the correct location:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/spatialite/index.html#spatialite-install

Any help finding the 2.17 spatialite plugin would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the spatialite datastore working!

Here are the steps:

1. Copy older version of SpatiaLite Plugin: (to geoserver\WEB-INF\lib)

geoserver-2.7-SNAPSHOT-spatialite-plugin.zip

2. Copy the supporting GEOS/PROJ libs to the C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder:

spatialite-libs-win-x86.zip

3. Make sure you have also installed the sqlite plugin from 2.17:

geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-gwc-sqlite-plugin.zip

Comment: that might work for now, but in general you should use the new GeoPackage store if you need a simple file based database

Answer (score 0):

The spatialite datastore was killed off sometime ago. See https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/commit/aaa66d89add2759f152caf4fe94b4e79cac251a2